# What is the Big-O of String.contains in OCaml?

Tags: string, ocaml, big-o

What is the Big-O of using `String.contains()` in OCaml? Does it iterate through each index, or is it O(1)?

Comment: You can look into the source code. [`String.contains`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/string.ml#L109), which calls [`Bytes.contains`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/bytes.ml#L250).

Answer (score 0):

It's `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of the string.

Comment: Do you have any way to verify that?

Comment: @Teepeemm, here the call stack: `String.contains` -> `Bytes.contains` -> `Bytes.contains_from` -> `Bytes.index_rec`. The last one is tail-recursive, with linear complexity. Here the essential part of it: `if unsafe_get s i = c then i else index_rec s lim (i + 1) c;;`. Note that `i` gets incremented by one in every recursive call, and it goes from `0` up to the length of the string; the recursion stops when the length of the string is reached: `if i >= lim then raise Not_found else`. Every separate step of the recursion is `O(1)`, hence the final `O(n)` complexity.

Comment: @Teepeemm, please see [the implementation of `Bytes.index_rec`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/bytes.ml#L218)